# My brackets bottom panel doesn't work

Tags: coffeescript, adobe-brackets

I try to do a Brackets extension ( the web editor ), and I have to create a bottom panel, but it never appear, 
the show method do nothing and setVisible too, 
can you tell me why? Thx...

```
define (require, exports, module)->
    log = (s)->
        console.log "%c[SQL-DISPLAY] " + s, "color:#f4aa05;font-size:large"
    log "started..."
    commandManager      = brackets.getModule "command/CommandManager"
    menus               = brackets.getModule "command/Menus"
    appInit             = brackets.getModule "utils/AppInit"
    dialogs             = brackets.getModule "widgets/Dialogs"
    defaultDialogs      = brackets.getModule "widgets/DefaultDialogs"
    workspaceManager    = brackets.getModule "view/WorkspaceManager"

    sql_display_execute = 'sql-display.execute' # mon entrée dans le menu
    panel = {}


    appInit.appReady ()->
        commandManager.register 'sql-display panel', sql_display_execute, handleSqlDisplay
        menu = menus.getMenu menus.AppMenuBar.VIEW_MENU
        menu.addMenuItem sql_display_execute

        panel = workspaceManager.createBottomPanel 'sql.display.execute', $(require('text!templates/panel.html')), 400

    handleSqlDisplay = ()->

        log "disp modal box"
        console.log panel

        console.log panel.isVisible() #always false
        # affiche une modal
        #dialogs.showModalDialog defaultDialogs.DIALOG_ID_INFO, "database informations", "<p>test</p>"
        if panel.isVisible()
            #panel.setVisible(false)
            panel.hide()
            commandManager.get(sql_display_execute).setChecked(false)
        else
            panel.show()
            console.log 'try to show'
            #panel.setVisible(true)
            commandManager.get(sql_display_execute).setChecked(true)

            while( !panel.isVisible)
                panel.show()

        console.log panel.isVisible()#always false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solve my problem, a bottom cannot open if you don't load a stylesheet ^^

```
extensionUtils = brackets.getModule "utils/ExtensionUtils"
extensionUtils.loadStyleSheet(module, "main.css");
```

with this, it's work...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your true problem, but this code will never run:

```
        while( !panel.isVisible)
            panel.show()
```

`panel.isVisible` will always evaluate to true, because isVisible is a function. You need the parentheses to actually call the function; they are not optional for zero-argument functions.

Comment: this is an attenpt to do something but I add parentheses and it's do nothing too. I dont know why the first panel.show() doesn't work (not in the while)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the html in the $panel parameter in WorkspaceManager.createBottomPanel requires a DOM id for the function to work correctly.

```
panel = WorkspaceManager.createBottomPanel(ID_OF_EXECUTE, $("<div id='some-id' class='bottom-panel'>HTML for my panel</div>"),200);
```

see [Brackets -WorkspaceManager (click show code)](http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/view/WorkspaceManager.html#-createBottomPanel)